# Start a screen then run a command from the screen

Tags: bash, debian

I want to use the `screen -x` command to enter a screen then run a command. I thought this would be easy:

```
screen -x
cd /ftb
java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -jar mcpc.jar
```

However that didn't work. It outputs the screen help and says `Error: Unknown option x` and `: No such file or directory 2: cd: /ftb` (including the `:`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your script file has DOS line endings; the unknown option is actually `-x\r`. You'll need to remove them, either by saving the file in your editor with UNIX line endings or running `dos2unix` on the file

Second, when `screen -x` succeeds, you are attached to the `screen` session, and the `screen -x` command will not exit until you detach, at which point your script can continue with the `cd` command. I think what you actually want is the `-X` option, which sends a command to an existing session.

```
screen -X 'cd /ftb; java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -jar mcpc.jar'
screen -x
```

Send the command to the session, *then* attach to it.